# Does anyone know of an server implementation of the WFS 2.0.2 standard

Tags: arcgis-server, wfs

I'm looking for either a public server than implements the WFS 2.0.2 standard or a reference implementation that I could run on my own copy of ArcGIS server.

I've googled for a long time and searched data.gov but found nothing but 2.0 implementations.

Comment: What is WFC? Is it somewhere in this list http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards?

Comment: Exactly, it is a [Web Feature Service](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) that usually corresponds with a WMS ( Web Map Service )

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the correct abbreviation for a Web Feature Service i.e.WFS, as opposed to the WFC you originally cited.

Answer (score 1):

In principle WFS 2.0 implies compliance to WFS 2.0.n it doesn't imply WFS 2.0.0, so you might need to check more closely that the servers you found that say they are compliant to WFS 2.0 aren't actually compliant to 2.0.2

That said, if you look at the [OGC list of Implementations by Specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/resource/products/stats)

You can see that only one product appears to be implementing WFS 2.0.2 and that is [Spatial Eye](http://www.spatial-eye.com/) X&Y server.